# How would I list decimal numbers in a dropdown menu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This would list numbers `5.0` to `7.0` in a drop select menu:

```
<%= f.select :height, (5..7).step(0.1) %>
```

How would I list `5.0` to `7.0` but also include an option of "Below 5.0" and "Above 7.0" as part of the menu?

I'm trying to create a dropdown/select menu for my users to select their height and wish to avoid doing it the long way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a helper method to do the construction (somewhat based on PinnyM's answer)

```
module MycontrollerHelper
  def decimal_selection_array(start,limit,step_size=1)
    decimal_array = (start..limit).step(step_size).map(&:to_s).to_a
    decimal_array.insert(0,"Below #{start.to_f}")
    decimal_array.insert(-1,"Above #{limit.to_f}")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= f.select :height, (5..7).step(0.1).to_a.insert(0, "Below 5.0").push("Above 7.0") %>
```

Although I don't think the view is generally the best place to do this...